# SVM bad input shape

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I created a dataset and split it into train and test sets.

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.20)
```

When I tried to implement a SVM classifier with the code below:

```py
from sklearn.svm import SVC
svc_classifier = SVC(kernel='rbf')
svc_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

`X_train.shape` and `y_train.shape` are both `(160,2)`.

When I run the last part I got **ValueError**: `bad input shape (160, 2)` error. I know my training and testing samples must be the same size. But I'm wondering if there is a method to deal with this problem. Thank you!

Comment: You are trying to use a classifier to predict a continuous target. That can't be right. Perhaps you might be interested in a Y of shape (160,1) or (160,) with integers let's say three values 0,1,2

Comment: @GaussianPrior, what would you suggest in this situation?

Comment: I see that this is a continuation of the problem you posted just a while ago. That coe has the names `X` and `Y` but they obviously doesn't represent training data and labels becasue both of them are your training data. You need to create a  label array `Y` separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that you want -

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC

std = [[0.5, 0], [0, 0.5]]
X1 = np.vstack((
    np.random.multivariate_normal([2, -2], std, size=200),
    np.random.multivariate_normal([-2, 2], std, size=200)
))
y1 = np.zeros(X1.shape[0])

X2 = np.vstack((
    np.random.multivariate_normal([2, 2], std, size=200),
    np.random.multivariate_normal([-2, -2], std, size=200)
))
y2 = np.ones(X2.shape[0])

X = np.vstack((X1, X2))
y = np.hstack((y1, y2))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20)
svc_classifier = SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma='auto')
svc_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The original code you are using to create your data was just has `Y` as the name. It is not supposed to represent the labels. You need to create labels separately.

Comment: I was just trying the solution you offered in the comment @Ananda, and it worked perfectly, thank you for sharing the code as well!

Comment: How do you think I can still plot the dataset to visualize it in two different colors? @Ananda

Comment: You will need to plot `X1` and `X2` separately. Or else you need to seperate them based on their label `Y`s.